# Cumulative count based on two categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to do, for each record in a table, a cumulative count based on two categorical columns.

In the following table, I'd like to get the *cum_count* column, which is calculated based on the columns *industry* and *deal_status*. The idea is, for each record, count the number of **previous** won deals for the same industry.

For example, the last record of the table has a *cum_count* = 3 because only 3 deals with *deal_status* = won for *industry* = x have been seen previously.

The [Pandas' GroupBy.cumcount function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) does that for a single variable...

How can I accomplish this for the case I describe?

```
pd.DataFrame({'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
              'company' : ["ciaA", "ciaB", "ciaA", "ciaC", "ciaA", "ciaD", "ciaE"],
              'industry' : ["x", "y", "x", "x", "x", "y", "x"],
              'deal_status' : ["won", "lost", "won", "won", "lost", "won", "lost"],
              'cum_count' : [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3]})


time    company    industry     deal_status     cum_count
 1       ciaA         x             won             0
 2       ciaB         y            lost             0
 3       ciaA         x             won             1
 4       ciaC         x             won             2
 5       ciaA         x            lost             3
 6       ciaD         y             won             0
 7       ciaE         x            lost             3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a helper column that you will take the cumulative sum of.  Need to shift within each group as your counts only include *previous* win values:

```
df['to_sum'] = (df.deal_status == 'won').astype(int)
df['cum_count'] = (df.groupby('industry')
                    .apply(lambda x: x.to_sum.shift(1).cumsum()).fillna(0)
                    .reset_index(0, drop=True))
```

#### Output `df`:

```
   time company industry deal_status  to_sum  cum_count
0     1    ciaA        x         won       1        0.0
1     2    ciaB        y        lost       0        0.0
2     3    ciaA        x         won       1        1.0
3     4    ciaC        x         won       1        2.0
4     5    ciaA        x        lost       0        3.0
5     6    ciaD        y         won       1        0.0
6     7    ciaE        x        lost       0        3.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. I had only come up with the groupby idea, none of the rest.